# is there a better performance's way to get only few columns in ASP MVC without getting the whole table and filter it with LinQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

im calling a table with 200.000 rows and 6 columns, but i only want 2 of these columns to be used in one controller, so i want to know if there is a better way to call them from the server without compromising performance, because as i know Linq queries get the whole table and them makes the filtering, i think maybe Views is a good way, but i want to know if there are others and betters, Thanks.

for example:

```
var items = from i in db.Items select new {i.id,i.name};
```

in case i have 1.000.000 items, will it be a trouble for the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial assumption is incorrect.

In general LINQ queries do not get the whole table. the query is converted into a "server side expression" (i.e. a SQL statement) and the statement is resolved on the server and only the requested data is returned.

Given the statement you provided you will return only two columns but you will get 1,000,000 objects in the result if you do not do any filtering. But that isn't a problem with LINQ, that's a problem with you not filtering. If you included a `where` clause you would only get the rows you requested.

```
var items = from i in db.Items
            where i.Whatever == SomeValue
            select new { i.id, i.name };
```

Your original query would be translated (roughly) into the following SQL:

```
SELECT id, name FROM Items
```

You didn't include a `where` clause so you're going to get everything.

With the version that included a `where` clause you'd get the following SQL generated:

```
SELECT id, name FROM Items WHERE Whatever = SomeValue
```

Only the rows that match the condition would be returned to your application and converted into objects.